# Set ARR under IIS with last-modified header for cache

Tags: iis, cache, arr

I want to set ARR (IIS load balancing software) with cache that depends on the `last-modified` tag in the header.

Every time the server gets a request it will look at the `last-modified` tag and if it's already cached it will take present the data that is in cache. However, if it's a page that hasn't been cached the server will show the original file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, ARR Proxy (and any other proxy-cache) use this header (and more) to check if something is in cache.

Open IIS root, and create a Server Farm with your needs.
You can also open  your website in IIS manager, URL Rewrite,  and add a Reverse Proxy rule with your needs (for example - proxy for only one folder in a working website).

Remember that you need  to configure a proxy rules (if not, the rewrite-proxy just not work). open your server farm (maybe need to create and delete) and configure in "Proxy" section.

I prefer use nginx or other software to load-balance servers. I like ASP.net and IIS fetures, but as a stupid-reverse-proxy use others.

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks, What other software I can use? I'm using Windows